# Is It safe around Old Market area in Bristol?

Tags: safety, accommodation, bristol

I am a newly UK resident/worker and looking for a place (for me and my wife-but no kids) in Bristol and found some flats at a [Saints Court](http://www.saintscourt.co.uk/). I did not read bad words about Old Market, St Jude or St Philips (these are the surrounding areas as far as I see) but considering the area being between St Paul and Easton kinda makes me suspicious about the safety. Does anyone have any advises for a newcomer to the UK about this particular area?

EDIT: I went to the house and saw that it is just before coming to the Stapleton Road from south-west side, (Footnote: this is also something interesting I've noticed at the UK; you may have the same road/street, but it has three different names as you walk on, e.g. from NW to SE -> Lamb Street becomes Lawfords Gate becomes Stapleton Road). Walked towards the Easton side (but not beyond Easton Way) of Stapleton Road and noticed that there is a huge immigrant population there, many markets and food places for halal food.

I have read that Stapleton Road is a dangerous place but is it so on the south-west side also, or those things happen usually east of Easton Way? I plan to live around 6 months-1 year there and the immigrant population, LGBT or the different cultural structure does not make me disturbed; but drugs, gangs or prostitution do (sorry--this is what I read about the Stapleton Road in this infamous controversial [article](http://www.mirror.co.uk/news/world-news/people-investigation-junkie-st-1612082)).

Comment: Are you planning a short vacation, or to move there more or less permanently?

Comment: more or less permanent, 6 mt.s~1yr. i've edited the question.

Comment: In that case you might be better served by [expatriates.se] which is geared toward long term living in a foreign country.

Comment: initially I asked there but it was taken on hold with the reason being of topic and advising here will be a better place :)

Comment: Yep, your question is enough between the charters of the two sites that both could reasonably say go to the other. We'll see what other answers get posted here. Me saying that and you giving your response as you did might forestall an on-hold here as well.

Comment: I feel safety of an area is fine to ask about on travel, whether your trip be for a week or 6 months, surely?

Comment: @CGCampbell also, it'd be offtopc on expats as it's not a question that affects expats differently from any locals asking about safety :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's worth noting that [Old Market is considered Bristol's Gay Village](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Market,_Bristol#Gay_Village) and some would see that as indicating that people are accommodating of different backgrounds, and that it's safe enough to be there.

We stayed very close there there 3.5 years ago, and out at night in town there were the usual drunken idiots you'd expect in the middle of a largeish city, but we didn't feel any less safe than anywhere else, really.  We had a great time - a cider festival was on at the time :D